# Is the sequence infinite? Finite? Is there a general formula to determine n th term?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, factorial, prime-factorization

Sequence of numbers whose factorial on prime factorisation contains prime powers of prime numbers, whose power is greater than $1$ or contains multiplicity of one for all prime numbers less than equal to number.

Sequence: $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 14, \ldots$

If $k$(prime) is to be checked for its presence in sequence, then if $k-1$ is in sequence, then $k$ is also in sequence.

$a(3)=4$ as $4!=(2^3)\cdot(3^1)$. Since multiplicity of $2$ is $3$, which is prime, and multiplicity of $3$ is $1$, so $4$ finds it's presence in the sequence.

Comment: How is $4$ in the sequence when in $4!$ neither "contains multiplicity of one for all prime numbers" nor multiplicity is greater than 1 fo rall prime numbers?

Comment: Read the question properly.

Comment: Do you mean to express that in the prime factorisation of $k!=\prod_pp^{\nu_p}$, all exponents $\nu_p$ are prime or $=1$ (or $=0$)?

Comment: Not for all k, it is possible but for some listed in the sequence in question

Comment: Not all prime numbers, prime numbers less than k, seen in prime factorisation of k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all large enough $k$, there will exist a prime $p$ with $4p\le k<5p\ll p^2$). Then we will have $p^4\mid k!$, but $p^5\nmid k!$ and $k$ is not in your sequence. The existence of such $p$  follows asymptotically from the Prime Number Theorem. However, we even have some [explicit bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Non-asymptotic_bounds_on_the_prime-counting_function) such as [Dusart 2010]
$$\frac x{\ln x-1}<\pi(x)<\frac x{\ln x-1.1}\qquad\text{if }x\ge 60184. $$
This makes $\pi(\tfrac k4)>\pi(\tfrac k5)$ at least for all $k$ with ($k\ge 5\cdot 60184$ and)
$$ \frac{\frac k4}{\ln\frac k4-1}>\frac{\frac k5}{\ln\frac k5-1.1}$$
and ths inequality is equivalent to 
$$ k>\frac{5^5e^{1.5}}{4^4}\approx 55.$$
Hence your sequence is finite and all terms in it are $< 300920$. By explicitly testing the few $k$ in the remaining range, we find that $\pi(\frac k4)>\pi(\frac k4)$ already holds for all 
$$ k>115.$$
Meanwhile the range is short enough to testing your condition completely. As it turns out, the *full* sequence is
$$ 1,2,3,4,5,8,14.$$

Comment: You can comment on http://oeis.org/draft/A330706 related to this sequence.

Comment: You can present your work on http://oeis.org/draft/A330706 ,whatever you proved here. I have not clearly understood your answer as I am lacking in prime number theorems, and its applications.